# Suggest Ranking algorithm for Multi User Sortable Lists

Tags: algorithm, math, ranking

I'm building a site where I am giving users the ability to drag and drop to order a list of items to rank them for their "personal view." They can optionally remove an item to hide it from their "personal view."

My question is how can I fairly implement a ranking algorithm to determine the ordering of the items for a shared view that doesn't penalize new items.

It would also help if that can also be used to rank where new items would show up in a users personal list.

So if a new item comes along that is highly ranked by other users, we could display it where we predict the user would rank it related to their other rankings.

My initial thoughts is give points to each item ranked by a user = to the position in a users ranked list. (ex. If there are 10 items, give rank 1 10 pts, 2 9 pts, etc, with negative points awarded for items hidden by the user). And the shared view would sort based on total points. But this would not work well for new items that were largely unranked, and would not easily move up the ladder.

So any thoughts on a fair algorithm that can be predictive for new items?

Comment: Ravloony's comment got me thinking better about the problem, and here is the algorithm I think will work.

When a user sorts a list, give each item a score = count of items + 1 - rank in the list / count of items. (1 of 3 = 1, 2 of 3 = .667, 2 of 5 = .8).

The items score is the average of all their users scores.

So as more items are added, newer items with higher rankings will float to the top.

This should work in general, but would make it easy for new entries to be ranked highly with few ratings. Any thoughts on how to add number of rankings to the weight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I have a working solution. By combining the approach I mentioned in the question comment, with the lower bound of [Wilson's score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) the score seems to align to my expectations.

So to rehash the approach from my comment: user item score = count of items + 1 - rank in the list / count of items. (1 of 3 = 1, 2 of 3 = .667, 2 of 5 = .8).

to give an overall item score I plug into the Wilson formula:
(phat + z*z/(2*n) - z * Math.sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n)

Where phat = average of scores, n is number of rankings, z=1.96 (for a 95% confidence ranking).

I mocked up some data in Excel and played around with different scenarios and liked the results. Will move to implementation. Thanks for the help

Comment: can you please elaborate on what do you mean when you by Z ?!

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing something similar to 9gag ranking system. You can have a shared page where highest ranking items show up and a voting page where users can see new items and rank them accordingly.

Comment: Don't think that approach fits. The site will have multiple topics, and each topic can have a list of items that can be added to. This page will use jquery sortables to allow users to order a list any way they like for their "personal" view, but they can switch to the shared view or new view. Even for the personal view, I would like to predict where to put new items as it will be the default view for users who have previously sorted the items.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important point here is to look at what other users ranking are with respect to other items as well.

"This item is often ranked 3rd" is not useful, I think, whereas "Item under consideration (which we shall call A) is **ranked better than** item B most of the time" is, because it allows you to create a (maybe fuzzy) ordering of your list of items under consideration.

Essentially, for a new item in a users list, you would implement a kind of insertion sort, where the comparison of two elements is determined by their average order within other peoples lists. In fact, any sort algorithm would work, as long as it depends on having an order between two given elements.

Comment: So would this mean I could calculate a score for the item, by taking the mean rank (percentage wise 3 of 6 vs. 2 of 10) where the item was ranked and use that to figure out how it stacks against other items which may have more rankings?

Comment: Well what I meant was that as you compared each pair of items, you worked out whether one was usually ranked higher than the other by the other users. But in fact that might turn out to be too expensive. However calculating a score for each element would be difficult too, given that the system is dynamic, so you would have to recalculate a lot of the scores a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

here is my Wilson's score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter in node.js

```
wilson.normaldist = function(qn) {
    var b = [1.570796288, 0.03706987906, -0.0008364353589, -0.0002250947176, 0.000006841218299, 0.000005824238515, -0.00000104527497, 0.00000008360937017, -0.000000003231081277, 0.00000000003657763036, 0.0000000000006936233982];
    if (qn < 0.0 || 1.0 < qn) return 0;
    if (qn == 0.5) return 0;
    var w1 = qn;
    if (qn > 0.5) w1 = 1.0 - w1;
    var w3 = -Math.log(4.0 * w1 * (1.0 - w1));
    w1 = b[0];

    function loop(i) {
        w1 += b[i] * Math.pow(w3, i);
        if (i < b.length - 1) loop(++i);
    };
    loop(1);
    if (qn > 0.5) return Math.sqrt(w1 * w3);
    else return -Math.sqrt(w1 * w3);
}

wilson.rank = function(up_votes, down_votes) {
    var confidence = 0.95;
    var pos = up_votes;
    var n = up_votes + down_votes;
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    var z = this.normaldist(1 - (1 - confidence) / 2);
    var phat = 1.0 * pos / n;
    return ((phat + z * z / (2 * n) - z * Math.sqrt((phat * (1 - phat) + z * z / (4 * n)) / n)) / (1 + z * z / n)) * 10000;
}
```